# OpenTK GetState function returning incorrect values

Tags: c#, opentk

I'm experiencing incorrect return values from OpenTK's `GetState` function.

The code below calculates how far the mouse has moved since the previous frame, writing the x distance the the console.

```
    Vector2 lastMousePos;

    public static void MouseLook(Game game)
    {   
        Vector2 delta = lastMousePos - new Vector2(OpenTK.Input.Mouse.GetState().X, OpenTK.Input.Mouse.GetState().Y);
        lastMousePos += delta;

        Console.WriteLine (delta.X);
    }
```

However, scrolling the mouse at a more or less constant rate produces the following values:

```
17
0
18
0
18
12
11
20
0
31
0
34
0
26
0
19
```

These zero values are causing a visible jerk when mouselooking. Any ideas what is causing them?

Comment: Have you considered that really there is no mouse position change on that frame?

Comment: Sure, it's possible, and that is good idea, I'll look into it. For now, I'm taking an average of the last 5 positions and it has fixed the issue.